# How to post image to server using urlread() in MATLAB

Tags: url, matlab, post, file-upload

I want to use face.com face detection API (send an image to a server and get back an xml string result).

I use `urlread()` and it cannot upload an image file.

the code:

```
fid = fopen('T000.jpg');
im  = fread(fid,Inf,'*uint8');
fclose(fid);

urlread('http://api.face.com/faces/detect.xml','post',...
        {'api_key'      , MY_CODE,...
         'api_secret'   , MY_SECRET,...
         'detector'     , 'Normal',...
         'attributes'   , 'all',...
         'file'         , im})
```

But it returns an error because MATLAB tries to encode the image as url.

Note: when I use an image on the web it does work (since no file is uploaded).

```
urlread('http://api.face.com/faces/detect.xml','post',...
        {'api_key'      , MY_CODE,...
         'api_secret'   , MY_SECRET,...
         'detector'     , 'Normal',...
         'attributes'   , 'all',...
         'urls'         , 'http://0.tqn.com/d/beauty/1/0/x/3/1/halle_berry_pixie.jpg'})
```

Comment: I edited the first word of the question, from 'Hot' to 'How'.  If in fact it's not a question of how to do something but a statement that you are keen or under pressure to do something, I do apologise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer. An alternative implementation to urlread() [on the File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27189-urlreadpost-url-post-method-with-binary-file-uploading/content/urlreadpost.m).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot use the builtin function `urlread`. It only uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for POST requests and the [face API](http://developers.face.com/docs/api/faces-detect/) needs `multipart/form-data` in order to upload jpeg files. You would have to look at third party tools

Alternatively you could try writing your own modified urlread function. However Matlab does not have more fine grained access than urlread. To solve this you can use [Java within Matlab](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f44062.html). The docs even contain a [URL example](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f16555.html). Basically you can create Java objects and call their methods in the Matlab interpreter. Here is an example of Java inside Matlab:

```
string_builder = java.lang.StringBuilder('Bar'); %new is not used
string_builder.setCharAt(2, 'z');
java_string = string_builder.toString.toLowerCase; %brackets are optional
matlab_char = char(java_string); %matlab_char == 'baz'
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Mathworks created `webread` and `webwrite` to address this in newer versions of Matlab.